# priority_queue class field using a comparator that access another class field

Tags: c++, priority-queue

Hello I need to create a class which contains a priority_queue field whose comparator function needs to access another field in the class. In short I need to write something like this:

```
class A
{
    B foo;
    priority_queue<C,vector<C>,comparator> bar;
}
```

where the comparator definition is something like

```
bool comparator(const C& c1, const C& c2)
{
    //compute the boolean value using c1, c2 and the field foo
}
```

Is it possible to obtain this result in some way and where I have to define the comparator function?

Comment: Use a capturing lambda for the comparator.

Comment: @RichardCritten already tried with capturing lambda (`[&]` if I'm correct), but it gives me the following error : `‘this’ was not captured for this lambda function`. I've tried also to define an auto field storing the lambda function but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two steps to do this.

First, your comparator needs a constructor that saves a reference to an instance of `A`

```
class comparator {

     A &a;

public:
     comparator(A &a_arg) : a(a_arg)
     {
     }

     bool operator()(const C &first, const C &second) const
     {
          // The comparator can use "a" to access the contents of the
          // A class.
     }
};
```

And the second step is for `A`'s constructor to initialize its `priority_queue` member using an explicit `comparator` that gets constructed from `*this`:

```
A::A() : bar(comparator(*this))
{
   // ...
}
```

Note: keep in mind the reference to `*this` in the comparator. If the instance of `A` gets copied, the `this` reference will not be valid in the copy. Your `A` class should have either a `delete`d copy-constructor, or an explicit copy-constructor that initializes the copy-constructed `A` `priority_queue`, accordingly.

Comment: If I use this method I have the problem to forward declare one of the two classes, but I cannot because I use the forwarded class without pointer or references (respectively in the operator() method, and in the priority_queue field declaration). Should I change the A reference to an A pointer?

Comment: Pointer or reference makes no difference. Only declare `operator()` in the `comparator` class declaration, then define it after the main class is defined (with `inline`). Problem solved.

Comment: It works now, though it seems to me to be a little complicated. Anyway thank you for the help sir.

Comment: @user3760875 - nobody has ever accused C++ of being simple.